# using quote() and eval() from within a function

Tags: r

How can I use parameters defined by a function when they are included in a `quote()` that is evaluated using `eval()`

For example, in the below: how do I make this into a function in which a user can update **newdataA** and **newdataB** with new parameters via arguments to a function. Since **newdataA** and **newdataB** are included in the `quote()`, I wasn't sure how to get R to recognize new values specified from within a function.

```
library(survey)
data(nhanes)
nhanesdesign <- svydesign(id=~SDMVPSU, strata=~SDMVSTRA, weights=~WTMEC2YR, nest=TRUE,data=nhanes)

logistic <- svyglm(HI_CHOL~race+RIAGENDR, design=as.svrepdesign(nhanesdesign),
 family=quasibinomial, return.replicates=TRUE)

bootdesign<- as.svrepdesign(nhanesdesign, type ="bootstrap", replicates = 100)

newdataA <- data.frame(race=1, RIAGENDR=2)
newdataB <- data.frame(race=2, RIAGENDR=2)


fit <- withReplicates(bootdesign, 
              quote(
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata=newdataA) / 
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata=newdataB))) 
                                                           

demofunc <- function(racea,gendera,
                     raceb,genderb){
    dataa<- data.frame(race=racea, RIAGENDR=gendera )
    datab<- data.frame(race=raceb, RIAGENDR=genderb )   
    bootdesign<- as.svrepdesign(nhanesdesign, type ="bootstrap", replicates = 100)
    temp <-  withReplicates(bootdesign, 
              quote(
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata=dataa) / 
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata=datab))) 
    return(temp)
}


demofunc(racea=1,gendera=2,
         raceb=2,genderb=2)
```

This gives me an error that dataa and datab aren't found

Comment: Could you post the function you have in mind? It's not clear what's going wrong without seeing it.

Comment: If you are passing newdataA, newdataB, which already have the columns for RIAGENDR, race, there is no need for `racea`, `gendera`, `raceb`, genderb parameters

Comment: I'd like to eventually put it into a shiny app where the user can specify those racea, gendera, raceb, etc parameters.

Comment: @kf86 well, then do you don't need the `newdata` parameter because that is what it is creating.  Or if you are passing those as parameters, then inside the function, construct the 'newdataA', 'newdataB'

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm understanding what you mean - could you provide an example? The code you had provided isn't working in that environment (e.g., "error in predict.lm: object 'dataa' not found)

Comment: @kf86 you could check my update.

Answer (score 0):

We may create a string interpolation with `glue` from the input string dataframe object names, `parse` it to language and then use that in `withReplicates`

```
f1 <- function(dat1, dat2) {
       v1 <- parse(text = glue::glue("predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata={dat1}) / 
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata= {dat2})"))[[1]]
   withReplicates(bootdesign, v1)

}
```

-testing

```
f1('newdataA', 'newdataB')
 theta     SE
1 0.97932 0.0247
```

-checking with OP's output outside the function

```
> fit
    theta     SE
1 0.97932 0.0247
```

---

Regarding the issue in finding the object, it is related to `withReplicates`.  According to the documentation of `?withReplicates`

> It is possible to use global variables in the expression, but unwise, as they may be masked by local variables inside withReplicates.

It may be looking for global variables and therefore, if we create a local environment or assign objects globally it works

```
demofunc <- function(racea,gendera,
                     raceb,genderb){
    dataa <<- data.frame(race=racea, RIAGENDR=gendera )
    datab <<- data.frame(race=raceb, RIAGENDR=genderb ) 
     
    data(nhanes)
    nhanesdesign <- svydesign(id=~SDMVPSU, strata=~SDMVSTRA, weights=~WTMEC2YR, nest=TRUE,data=nhanes)

    
    bootdesign<- as.svrepdesign(nhanesdesign, type ="bootstrap", replicates = 100)
       v1 <- parse(text = glue::glue("predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata= dataa) / 
              predict(
                     glm(HI_CHOL ~ race+RIAGENDR, weights=.weights,
                     family=quasibinomial),
                     newdata= datab)"))[[1]]
   withReplicates(bootdesign, v1)
   
}
```

-testing

```
demofunc(racea=1,gendera=2,
         raceb=2,genderb=2)
   theta     SE
1 0.97932 0.0224
```